# js: Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined

Tags: javascript, python, html, pyqt5

Well I am working on project which requires map in python so I found that you can use leaflet and PyQt5 for that and then this error occured. I have 2 files only. map.html and map.py.

Here's map.html:-

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Ship Map</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="height: 100vh;"></div>

<script>
  // Wrap your code in a function that runs when the document is ready
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var mymap = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2);
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: '© OpenStreetMap contributors'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    var shipIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: 'E:\\Project CS\\Vessel Traffic Management System\\GUI\\photos\\ship.png',
      iconSize: [64, 64],
      iconAnchor: [16, 16],
      popupAnchor: [0, -16]
    });

    var ships = [
      { Embarkation: [18.9750, 72.8258], Name: 'Ship1' },
      { Embarkation: [13.0827, 80.2707], Name: 'Ship2' },
      // ... other ships
    ];

    console.log('hello')

    // Add markers for ships
    ships.forEach(function (ship) {
      var marker = L.marker(ship.Embarkation, { icon: shipIcon }).addTo(mymap);
      marker.bindPopup("<b>" + ship.Name + "</b>").openPopup();
    });
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And then there is map.py file.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import random

class MapApp(QMainWindow):
    class ships:
        speed = 0
        
        def __init__(self,Name,TYPE,IMO,Capacity,Condition,Navigation_Status,Embarkation,Departure_Time,Departure,Arrival_Time,Image):
            self.Name = Name
            self.IMO = IMO
            self.Condition = Condition
            self.Capacity = Capacity
            self.Navigation_Status = Navigation_Status
            self.Type = TYPE
            self.Embarkation = Embarkation
            self.Departure_Time = Departure_Time
            self.Departure = Departure
            self.Arrival_Time = Arrival_Time
            self.Image = Image

        @classmethod
        def change_condition(cls, condition):
            cls.condition = condition
        
        @classmethod
        def change_navigation_status(cls, navigation_status):
            cls.navigation_status = navigation_status

        def update_speed(self):
            self.speed = random.randint(25, 30)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Map App")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        # Create QWebEngineView
        self.web_view = QWebEngineView()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.web_view)

        # Load HTML file
        self.web_view.setUrl(QUrl.fromLocalFile("E:\Project CS\Vessel Traffic Management System\GUI\map.html"))

        # Create a list to store ship objects
        self.ship_objects = []

        # Create ship objects
        self.create_ships()

        self.update_map()

    def create_ships(self):
        # Create ship objects and append to the list
        ship1 = self.ships(Name="Eren", TYPE="Type1", IMO="IMO1", Capacity=100, Condition="Good",
                           Navigation_Status="Active", Embarkation=[0, 0], Departure_Time="Time1",
                           Departure="Departure1", Arrival_Time="Arrival1", Image="Image1")
        ship2 = self.ships(Name="Mikasa", TYPE="Type2", IMO="IMO2", Capacity=150, Condition="Excellent",
                           Navigation_Status="Inactive", Embarkation=[10, 10], Departure_Time="Time2",
                           Departure="Departure2", Arrival_Time="Arrival2", Image="Image2")

        # Append ship objects to the list
        self.ship_objects.append(ship1)
        self.ship_objects.append(ship2)

    def update_map(self):
        # Loop through ships and create markers
        js_commands = []
        
        for ship in self.ship_objects:
            # Extract latitude and longitude from Embarkation
            lat, lng = ship.Embarkation

            # Create JavaScript code for adding a marker
            js_command = f"L.marker([{lat},{lng}]).addTo(mymap).bindPopup('{ship.Name}');"
            js_commands.append(js_command)

        # Join all JavaScript commands into a single string
        js_code = "\n".join(js_commands)

        # Execute JavaScript code in the WebView
        self.web_view.page().runJavaScript(js_code)
        print('hello')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MapApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I was trying to mark some location on map using a class. But the ship class objects are not marked

I tried to get help with Chat GPT but he couldn't fix it

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: maybe you should use special module [pyqtlet](https://github.com/skylarkdrones/pyqtlet). Eventually you could check its source code. Maybe it needs special methods to run `<script ... leaflet.js"></script>` which creates `L`. Maybe it needs more time to run it.